# ASP.NET download menu from a link

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

I have a download button that when clicked, redirects to a file for download.
Example:

> Response.Redirect("http://www.example.com/data/file1.zip");

when this button is clicked you get a menu in that you can press OK to download.

But if I have the following:

> Response.Redirect("http://www.example.com/data/textfile.txt");

I get a piece of text instead. I don't want this behavior.

How can I make a menu pop all cases when you click to download the file.

I tried the following:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";

Response.Redirect("http://www.example.com/data/" + filename);
```

But if I click on it I still just get the contents of the txt in the browser. Is there any way to check if this mime type is actually being applied?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the response type,

octet-stream should force the user to open or save the file

something like

```
public class Download : IHttpHandler {
    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
        string filename = context.Request.QueryString["file"];
        string file = context.Server.MapPath(filename);
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(filename));
        try
        {
            context.Response.TransmitFile(file);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SendFailedDownload(filename, context);
        }
        finally
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: better still consider writing a .ashx handler and then you wouldn't need to redirect the response.

Answer (score 0):

instead of doing the above just use a link tag and set the href to the url of the file. This will not require redirection or adjusting the context.

```
<a href="<link to file>" title="">Download me </a>
```

and this will prompt you to save or open...

**doesnt work for txt files, does work for other files though**

Comment: This would actually open the .txt files into the same window which he wants to avoid. While using Kolin's answer it will force the browser to open a Save/Open dialog.

Comment: you are right, this doesnt work for txt files, must have read over that part ;)